# No io module after building python

Tags: python, linux, arm, embedded-linux

I used info from [this](http://www.trevorbowen.com/2013/10/07/cross-compiling-python-2-7-5-for-embedded-linux/) tutorial to cross-compile python 2.7.5 for embedded linux. Now when I try to install setuptools which needs `io` module I can see that it's not actually in there:

But I don't see there any excludes so I can't figure out why it isn't built.

```
root@dm365-evm:~/setuptools-4.0.1# python setup.py install                                                                                                         
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>                                                                                                          
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                 
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                             
    import io                                                                                                                                                      
  File "/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>                                                                                                                
    import _io                                                                                                                                                     
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Comment: Do you have a `/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so` file? Or a `lib-dynload` directory at all?

Comment: No, I hadn't got this file. I was able to build only python 2.7.3 and `_io` is there.